# Clean way of structuring ctypes class

Tags: python, ctypes, ffi

I've defined a `ctypes` class and an associated convenience function like so:

```
class BNG_FFITuple(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_uint32),
                ("b", c_uint32)]


class BNG_FFIArray(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("data", c_void_p),
                ("len", c_size_t)]

    # Allow implicit conversions from a sequence of 32-bit unsigned ints
    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, seq):
        return seq if isinstance(seq, cls) else cls(seq)

    def __init__(self, seq, data_type = c_float):
        array_type = data_type * len(seq)
        raw_seq = array_type(*seq)
        self.data = cast(raw_seq, c_void_p)
        self.len = len(seq)


def bng_void_array_to_tuple_list(array, _func, _args):
    res = cast(array.data, POINTER(BNG_FFITuple * array.len))[0]
    return res

convert = lib.convert_to_bng
convert.argtypes = (BNG_FFIArray, BNG_FFIArray)
convert.restype = BNG_FFIArray
convert.errcheck = bng_void_array_to_tuple_list
drop_array = lib.drop_array 
drop_array.argtypes = (POINTER(BNG_FFIArray),)
```

I then define a simple convenience function:

```
def f(a, b):
    return [(i.a, i.b) for i in iter(convert(a, b))]
```

Most of this works perfectly, but I have two issues:

- It's not flexible enough; I'd like to be able to instantiate a `BNG_FFITuple` using `c_float` instead of `c_uint32` (so the fields are `c_float`), and vice versa, so the `BNG_FFIArray` `data_type` is `c_uint32`. I'm not clear on how to do this, though.
- I'd like to free the memory which is now owned by Python, by sending a `POINTER(BNG_FFIArray)` back to my dylib (see `drop_array` – I've already defined a function in my dylib), but I'm not sure at what point I should call it.

Is there a way of encapsulating all this in a neater, more Pythonic way, which is also safer? I'm concerned that without the memory cleanup being defined in a robust way (on `__exit__`? `__del__`?) That anything that goes wrong will lead to unfreed memory

Comment: Do you need the `BNG_FFITuple` as an FFI argument, or is it just for use in Python? If it's just used in Python you'd be better served by [collections.namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). Just define a separate `errcheck` function for `int` and `float` conversions. You can free the array in `BNG_FFIArray.__del__`, but use a class reference to `lib.drop_array` as `BNG_FFIArray._drop_array` to avoid problems with module teardown setting `lib` to `None` before the object's `__del__` finalizer ha been called.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; my dylib functions expect a struct with `data` and `len` fields with the appropriate types, but it doesn't have to be called anything specific.

Comment: You convert the result to a `BNG_FFITuple` array in `bng_void_array_to_tuple_list`. Do you ever pass the `BNG_FFITuple` back to your library? If not, there's no reason to use a ctypes struct for that instead of converting the result to a regular Python `tuple` or `namedtuple`. Once converted the `BNG_FFIArray` is the only reference to the array, so it's fine to use its `__del__` finalizer to call `drop_array`.

Comment: Ah, OK. No, it's a one-way trip; never gets used after `bng_void_array_to_tuple_list`.

Comment: Are you restricted to having your library allocate and return memory, or could you calculate the size of the return array and pass a pointer to it from Python as well (so that Python owns all the memory)?

Comment: Also, since ints and floats are different sizes, you'd need a flag to describe which one you are processing (or am I misunderstanding your question about that?)

Comment: @PatrickMaupin it's a 1:1 transformation, so theoretically I should be able to pass a pointer – I have no experience doing this from either the Python or the Rust side, though.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin I assume I'd need a flag, yep.

Comment: Two more questions: (1) are the inputs and outputs always the same type as each other, or could they be mixed; and (2) do you anticipate using, e.g. the same length over and over (would caching the type be useful)?

Comment: @PatrickMaupin 1. input floats always return ints, and vice versa. 2. The length is unfortunately arbitrary. Also, thinking more about your initial question, the memory-freeing call back to rust will have to remain.

Comment: In that case, would it be a performance hit for rust to do all the memory allocation?  You could have a function that you call that allocates a struct with conversion type flag, length, and pointers to your two inputs and your output (and allocates buffers for the inputs and outputs).   So you'd make 3 calls from Python:  allocate, convert, deallocate.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Hmm, maybe, though it's more of a rewrite than I'd anticipated on the rust side. Here's what I'm doing at the moment: https://github.com/urschrei/rust_bng/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L67-L74

Answer (score 3):

Since you have some control over the rust side, the cleanest thing to do would be to pre-allocate the result array from Python before the call, and pass everything in a single structure.

The code below assumes this modification, but also designates the place where you would do the deallocation if you cannot do this.

Note that if you do this sort of encapsulation, you do NOT need to specify things like the parameters and result processing for the library function, because you're only calling the actual function from a single place, and always with exactly the same kinds of parameters.

I don't know rust (and even my C is a bit rusty), but the code below assumes you redefine your rust to match the equivalent of something like this:

```
typedef struct FFIParams {
    int32 source_ints;
    int32 len;
    void * a;
    void * b;
    void * result;
} FFIParams;

void convert_to_bng(FFIParams *p) {
}
```

Here is the Python.  One final note -- this is not thread-safe, due to the reuse of the parameter structure.  That's easy enough to fix if needed.

```
from ctypes import c_uint32, c_float, c_size_t, c_void_p
from ctypes import Structure, POINTER, pointer, cast
from itertools import izip, islice

_test_standalone = __name__ == '__main__'

if _test_standalone:
    class lib(object):
        @staticmethod
        def convert_to_bng(ptr_params):
            params = ptr_params.contents
            source_ints = params.source_ints
            types = c_uint32, c_float
            if not source_ints:
                types = reversed(types)
            length = params.len
            src_type, dst_type = types
            src_type = POINTER(length * src_type)
            dst_type = POINTER(length * 2 * dst_type)
            a = cast(params.a, src_type).contents
            b = cast(params.b, src_type).contents
            result = cast(params.result, dst_type).contents

            # Assumes we are converting int to float or back...
            func = float if source_ints else int
            result[0::2] = map(func, a)
            result[1::2] = map(func, b)

class _BNG_FFIParams(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("source_ints", c_uint32),
                ("len", c_size_t),
                ("a", c_void_p),
                ("b", c_void_p),
                ("result", c_void_p)]

class _BNG_FFI(object):

    int_type = c_uint32
    float_type = c_float
    _array_type = type(10 * int_type)

    # This assumes we want the result to be opposite type.
    # Maybe I misunderstood this -- easily fixable if so.
    _result_type = {int_type: float_type, float_type: int_type}

    def __init__(self):
        my_params = _BNG_FFIParams()
        self._params = my_params
        self._pointer = POINTER(_BNG_FFIParams)(my_params)
        self._converter = lib.convert_to_bng


    def _getarray(self, seq, data_type):
        # Optimization for pre-allocated correct array type
        if type(type(seq)) == self._array_type and seq._type_ is data_type:
            print("Optimized!")
            return seq
        return (data_type * len(seq))(*seq)

    def __call__(self, a, b, data_type=float_type):
        length = len(a)
        if length != len(b):
            raise ValueError("Input lengths must be same")

        a, b = (self._getarray(x, data_type) for x in (a, b))

        # This has the salutary side-effect of insuring we were
        # passed a valid type
        result = (length * 2 * self._result_type[data_type])()

        params = self._params
        params.source_ints = data_type is self.int_type
        params.len = length
        params.a = cast(pointer(a), c_void_p)
        params.b = cast(pointer(b), c_void_p)
        params.result = cast(pointer(result), c_void_p)
        self._converter(self._pointer)

        evens = islice(result, 0, None, 2)
        odds = islice(result, 1, None, 2)
        result = list(izip(evens, odds))

        # If you have to have the converter allocate memory,
        # deallocate it here...

        return result

convert = _BNG_FFI()

if _test_standalone:
    print(convert([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], c_float))
    print(convert([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], c_uint32))
    print(convert([1, 2, 3], (c_uint32 * 3)(4, 5, 6), c_uint32))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a modified version of the code that allocates the return array in the called DLL.  Since that would be harder to test with pure Python, and since I don't know rust, I built a cheesy C library for the actual test:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct FFIParams {
    int source_ints;
    int len;
    void * a;
    void * b;
} FFIParams, *FFIParamsPtr;

typedef int * intptr;
typedef float * floatptr;

void * to_float(FFIParamsPtr p) {
    floatptr result;
    intptr a = p->a;
    intptr b = p->b;
    int i;
    int size = sizeof(result[0]) * 2 * p->len;
    result = malloc(size);
    printf("Allocated %x bytes at %x\n", size, (unsigned int)result);
    for (i = 0; i < p->len; i++) {
        result[i*2+0] = (float)(a[i]);
        result[i*2+1] = (float)(b[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

void * to_int(FFIParamsPtr p) {
    intptr result;
    floatptr a = p->a;
    floatptr b = p->b;
    int i;
    int size = sizeof(result[0]) * 2 * p->len;
    result = malloc(size);
    printf("Allocated %x bytes at %x\n", size, (unsigned int)result);
    for (i = 0; i < p->len; i++) {
        result[i*2+0] = (int)(a[i]);
        result[i*2+1] = (int)(b[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

void * convert_to_bng(FFIParamsPtr p) {
    if (p->source_ints)
        return to_float(p);
    return to_int(p);
}

void free_bng_mem(void * data) {
    printf("Deallocating memory at %x\n", (unsigned int)data);
    free(data);
}
```

Here is the Python code that calls it:

```
from ctypes import c_uint32, c_float, c_size_t, c_void_p
from ctypes import Structure, POINTER, pointer, cast, cdll
from itertools import izip, islice


class _BNG_FFIParams(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("source_ints", c_uint32),
                ("len", c_size_t),
                ("a", c_void_p),
                ("b", c_void_p)]

class _BNG_FFI(object):

    int_type = c_uint32
    float_type = c_float
    _array_type = type(10 * int_type)
    _lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./testlib.so')
    _converter = _lib.convert_to_bng
    _converter.restype = c_void_p
    _deallocate = _lib.free_bng_mem

    _result_type = {int_type: float_type,
                    float_type: int_type}

    def __init__(self):
        my_params = _BNG_FFIParams()
        self._params = my_params
        self._pointer = POINTER(_BNG_FFIParams)(my_params)


    def _getarray(self, seq, data_type):
        # Optimization for pre-allocated correct array type
        if type(type(seq)) == self._array_type and seq._type_ is data_type:
            print("Optimized!")
            return seq
        return (data_type * len(seq))(*seq)

    def __call__(self, a, b, data_type=float_type):
        length = len(a)
        if length != len(b):
            raise ValueError("Input lengths must be same")

        a, b = (self._getarray(x, data_type) for x in (a, b))

        # This has the salutary side-effect of insuring we were
        # passed a valid type
        result_type = POINTER(length * 2 * self._result_type[data_type])

        params = self._params
        params.source_ints = data_type is self.int_type
        params.len = length
        params.a = cast(pointer(a), c_void_p)
        params.b = cast(pointer(b), c_void_p)

        resptr = self._converter(self._pointer)
        result = cast(resptr, result_type).contents

        evens = islice(result, 0, None, 2)
        odds = islice(result, 1, None, 2)
        result = list(izip(evens, odds))

        self._deallocate(resptr)

        return result

convert = _BNG_FFI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(convert([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], c_float))
    print(convert([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], c_uint32))
    print(convert([1, 2, 3], (c_uint32 * 3)(4, 5, 6), c_uint32))
```

And here is the result when I executed it:

```
Allocated 18 bytes at 9088468
Deallocating memory at 9088468
[(1L, 4L), (2L, 5L), (3L, 6L)]
Allocated 18 bytes at 908a6b8
Deallocating memory at 908a6b8
[(1.0, 4.0), (2.0, 5.0), (3.0, 6.0)]
Optimized!
Allocated 18 bytes at 90e1ae0
Deallocating memory at 90e1ae0
[(1.0, 4.0), (2.0, 5.0), (3.0, 6.0)]
```

This happens to be a 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04 system. I used Python 2.7, and I built the library with `gcc --shared ffitest.c -o testlib.so -Wall`

Comment: This example is simple enough you wouldn't really need a structure -- you could just pass 4 parameters directly.  But your original question had a structure, and I decided to leave it in as an example for more complicated cases.  If you want to pass more than one parameter, just do it -- ctypes doesn't _require_ you to define the valid types in each position, it just _allows_ it, which is really useful when you are exposing a c function to higher level code, but not so useful when you are wrapping it and only calling it from one place.